# Why is the second LINQ query faster?

Tags: performance, linq

In this code:

```
static bool Spin(int WaitTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running task {0} : thread {1}]",
        Task.CurrentId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(WaitTime);
    return true;
}

public void DemoPLINQLong()
{
    var SomeBigNumber = 1000000;
    var sequence = Enumerable.Range(0, SomeBigNumber);
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    sequence.Where(i => Spin(SomeBigNumber));
    sw.Stop();
    var synchTime = sw.Elapsed;
    sw.Restart();
    sequence.Where(i => Spin(SomeBigNumber));
    sw.Stop();
    var asynchTime = sw.Elapsed;
    Console.WriteLine("Synchronous: {0}  Asynchronous: {1}",
        synchTime.ToString(), asynchTime.ToString());
}
```

The results are consistent:
Synchronous: 00:00:00.0021800  Asynchronous: 00:00:00.0000076

Why is the second LINQ query hundreds of times faster?  Is there some kind of caching going on?  How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DotNet caches and creates performance optimizations the first time anything is executed; this is known as a Just In Time environment (JIT). Upon subsequent calls to the same code, the run time environment can re-use the existing optimizations which is why you'll frequently see the first run of nearly anything being much slower than subsequent runs of the same code.

A couple of side notes about the posted code:

1. Not sure what the "Synchronous" and "Asynchronous" terms are referring to; both examples are the exact same thing and there is nothing Asynchronous about them.
2. If you're not aware, none of the LINQ is being evaluated in the example due to the nature of LINQ's deferred execution. You can see this behavior if you change the example from: `sequence.Where(i => Spin(SomeBigNumber))` to `sequence.Where(i => Spin(SomeBigNumber)).ToList()`. Where, ToList() will force the evaluation of the LINQ predicate and the Console.WriteLine will be written to the console in the `Spin` method.

Comment: Yeah, it was the deferred execution.  When I added "ToList()" to both, the results were: "Synchronous: 00:00:10.9436257  Asynchronous: 00:00:10.9163481"  Much better.

Comment: BTW, the Synch/asynch thing -- I'm doing testing on PLINQ. I just needed to get a baseline first. Thx for helping me with that.